# What is 'focus' within the Android API?

Tags: java, android, focus

Simple question, but I can't seem to find a good answer within the Android docs. What exactly does it mean when a view has `focus`?

More specifically, if using a `RadioGroup`, can I access the selected child `RadioButton` by using something like the following?

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(radiogroup);
RadioButton activeChild = rg.getFocusedChild();
```

My thought was that this would not work... so I started to investigate exactly what `focus` was. But alas, I've been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the selected child, not the focused child. Focus in Android refers to a mode that's only used for dpad/trackball selection. You probably want `getCheckedRadioButtonId()`.